# can anyone explain me the impact of using Little endian or Big Endian representation of Numeric Type in java?

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to understand the serialization mechanism used in [RoaringBitmap](https://github.com/lemire/RoaringBitmap/tree/runcontainer). 
I have noticed that while serializing any numeric type (Integer/Long/Short) it is converted to reverseBytes (via `XXX.reverseBytes()`) methods. Is it some kind of optimization?

Comment: I'm not posting an answer because I don't know exactly what's happening in this case.  But the fact is, when machines store 32-bit (or 64- or 16-bit) integers in memory, some will store it with the most significant bits in the byte at the lowest address (big-endian), and some will store it with the least significant bits in the byte at the lowest address (little-endian).  When you're sending or storing bytes on one machine that might be read by another machine, there has to be _one_ standard endianness, which means some machines will have to reverse the byte order.

Comment: In my case the object will be created and used on single machine so i guess its not useful for me then?

Comment: Well, you never know--you or someone else may decide to bring up your app on a distributed system in the future.  But you're right, it might not be useful.  I don't know anything about `RoaringBitmap`, so I don't know if there's an option to use native machine order (i.e. turn off the byte reversal).

Comment: The author probably just wanted to follow the standard Network Byte Order, which is BigEndian.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with optimization. It about how a multi-byte numeric value is stored as a sequence of single bytes.

See this wiki article for more information about [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).